# Which Distributions can be Compiled using RandomVariate

Tags: probability-or-statistics, compile, random

Recently, Oleksandr kindly showed a [list of Mathematica commands that can be compiled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions). 
RandomVariate was part of that list. However, whether this can be compiled depends upon the distribution that is being sampled.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

cf1 = Compile[{{m, _Real}, {s, _Real}},
  Module[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6},
   v1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[m, s]];
   v2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{m, s}]];
   v3 = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[m, s]];
   v4 = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[m]];
   v5 = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[m]];
   v6 = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[m]];
   {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}
   ]
  ]
```

Using CompilePrint shows that RandomVariate can be compiled for the Normal Distribution or the Uniform Distribution and not with some others.

```
CompilePrint[cf1]

2 arguments
        4 Integer registers
        8 Real registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        R1 = A2
        Result = T(R1)0

1   R2 = RandomNormal[ R0, R1]]
2   R3 = RandomReal[ R0, R1]]
3   I0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{m, s}, 
             RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[m, s]]][ R0, R1]]
4   I1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{m, s}, 
             RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[m]]][ R0, R1]]
5   I2 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{m, s}, 
             RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[m]]][ R0, R1]]
6   I3 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{m, s}, 
             RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[m]]][ R0, R1]]
7   R4 = I0
8   R5 = I1
9   R6 = I2
10  R7 = I3
11  T(R1)0 ={ R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7 }
12  Return
```

Does anyone have a list of all the distributions that can be compiled (including, PDF, CDF and RandomVariate functionality)?

Comment: Well, you can check each of them, or semi-automate checking.  When one is not compiled, and you try to use it, you'll easily find out anyway:  see my answer to that post asking about compilable functions.

Comment: @szabolcs There are too many combinations to try out, unfortunately.

Comment: Beta distribution can be compiled too..

Comment: Since the results of `RandomVariate` are ALWAYS going to be Reals (for a continuous distribution), and Integers (for most inbuilt discrete distributions), I can't see why there would be any advantage to compiling them, that could not have automatically been built into the function. Does anyone have some timing tests where manual compilation yields substantive benefits to something like:  `RandomVariate[ dist, {10^6}]` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To my knowledge `UniformDistribution` and `NormalDistribution` are the only distributions that are directly compilable for `RandomVariate`.

Consider that sampling from a `UniformDistribution` is what `RandomReal` was originally designed to do.  This code is likely written deep down in C and so compiles without any special effort.  In order to hook up `RandomVariate` for uniforms `Compile` just needs to recognize that this is really just a call to `RandomReal`.

Now, sampling from a `NormalDistribution` is so common that it was considered worth the time investment to make it compilable.  Notice that the call to `RandomVariate` actually produces a call to `RandomNormal` which was almost certainly written for this purpose.

As for other distributions, special code would need to be written for each one in a similar fashion to `RandomNormal` for them to be "supported" by `Compile`. Since there are well over 100 of these, it would be a huge undertaking.  An argument could be made for doing this for a few distributions but who is to decide which ones are most important?

There is a sunny side. Most distributions have their own dedicated and highly optimized methods for random number generation. Often `Compile` is used under the hood when machine precision numbers are requested.

Because of this, even if they were directly compilable you probably wouldn't see much of a speed boost since the code is already optimized.

Fortunately `Compile` can happily handle arrays of numbers.  I typically just rely on the optimized code used by `RandomVariate` to generate the numbers and subsequently pass them in as an argument to the compiled function.

Incidentally, everything I just said about `RandomVariate` is also true of distribution functions like `PDF`, `CDF`, etc. Obviously these are just pure functions (in the univariate case) and unless they are built with some exotic components they should compile assuming you evaluate them before putting them into your compiled function.

Comment: Also of note is that `Erf[]` is in the list of compilable functions in Olek's answer. So yes, I think the normal distribution is pretty well-covered here.

Comment: I just found out that `RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[a,b]]` can also be compiled. By the way, it is not always that simple to generate the random numbers before passing them to a compiled function, especially, if the number of draws are endogenously determined within the function, as part of some while loop.

Comment: @asim this is definitely true.  I was unaware the `BetaDistribution` was compilable, thanks!

Comment: @asim I have had situations like this.  Typically I generate far more numbers than I think I will need and pass them in. It is faster to generate a bunch in one go than to repeatedly call `RandomVariate`. The downside is having to leave `Compile` and generate more if I didn't generate enough numbers in the first go.

Answer (score 20):

Another option to the answer posted by [Andy Ross](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43/andy-ross) cropped up in a recent question of mine about [corrupting an image with Poisson noise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56180/speed-up-adding-poisson-noise-to-an-image). In my own answer, I made use of `LibraryLink` to utilise the [distributions built into C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

This was especially useful in my case because Poisson noise in an image otherwise relies on a call to `RandomVariate` for each pixel (although the built-in Mathematica function for doing this via `ImageEffect` works differently, but is still slower than my answer).

Repeated calls to `RandomVariate` rapidly become time-consuming. Here I can get a ~200x speed-up!

```
(* Generate random list *)
listofnums1d = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {10^6}];

(* Calling RandomVariate each time takes 146.78 seconds *)
RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[#]] & /@ listofnums1d; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Loading my C++ function via LibraryLink (code below) takes 0.77 seconds *) 
mypoissondistribution[listofnums1d]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

C++ has a whole host of distributions built into `<random>`, including Gamma, Exponential, ChiSquare, Cauchy and Weibull.

If repeated calls to `RandomVariate` are a problem, this could be a way to go.

---

### C++ and `LibraryLink` code

```cpp
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){return WolframLibraryVersion;}
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {return 0;}
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int poissondistribution(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){

    int err; // error code

    MTensor m1; // input tensor
    MTensor m2; // output tensor

    mint const* dims; // dimensions of the tensor

    double* data1; // actual data of the input tensor
    double* data2; // data for the output tensor

    mint i; // bean counter

    m1 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    dims = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(m1);
    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, 1, dims,&m2);
    data1 = libData->MTensor_getRealData(m1);
    data2 = libData->MTensor_getRealData(m2);

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine generator (seed); // RNG

    for(i=0;i<dims[0];i++) {
        if(data1[i]==0.)
        {
            data2[i] = 0.; 
            // If value is 0, return 0. 
            // You can avoid this by not passing a value of 0, of course.
        }
        else
        {
            std::poisson_distribution<int> poissondistribution(data1[i]); // Poisson distribution
            data2[i] = poissondistribution(generator); // If value is >0, sample from the Poisson distribution
        }
    }

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, m2);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Put the C++ code into a file (e.g. in the notebook directory) and you can compile it like this.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

distributionlib = 
  CreateLibrary[{FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "filename"}]},
  "libraryname", "Debug" -> False, 
  "CompileOptions" -> "-O2 -std=c++11"];
```

Once the library has been compiled and you stop making changes to the C++ code, you can save time by taking it from the default location Mathematica places it (`$LibraryPath`, found using [`FindLibrary[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindLibrary.html)), and move it into your notebook directory and call it. Remember that the file extension is .dll on Windows, .so on Linux, and .dylib on Mac.

This works because [`LibraryFunctionLoad[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) uses `FindLibrary` internally.

```
mypoissondistribution = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "filename"}], 
   "functionname", {{Real, 1}}, {Real, 1}];
```

Note that this code takes and returns a 1D list of values. The code in my linked question about images takes a 2D list.

I believe that you can then include `mypoissondistribution` in a compiled function without a call to `MainEvaluate`. **Perhaps someone can clarify?** I don't know if you need to set `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` and/or `"InlineCompiledFunctions"` to `True` for this to work.

Comment: This is very neat!! +1

Answer (score 9):

Here is a quick (and dirty?) implementation of the Laplace distribution. Relationship to the uniform distribution as given [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Generating_random_variables_according_to_the_Laplace_distribution):

```
randomLaplace = With[{$MachineEpsilon = $MachineEpsilon},
  Compile[{{µ, _Real, 0}, {b, _Real, 0}, {n, _Integer, 0}},
   With[{u = RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2} (1 - $MachineEpsilon), n]},
    µ - b Sign[u] Log[1 - 2 Abs[u]]
   ]
  ]
 ];
```

[image: Histogram of compiled Laplace distribution results]

It looks fine compared to the built-in version:

[image: Histogram of built-in Laplace distribution results]

Answer (score 3):

Another distribution which is missing is `MultinormalDistribution[v,S]`. However, variates from this distribution are just affine transformations of vectors of iid normal variates. Indeed, if `y=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],Length@s]`, then `x=v+A.y` has the distribution of interest, where `A` is any decomposition of `S` such that `S==A.Transpose[A]`.

Since `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],{d1,d2,..}]` can be compiled, it suffices to implement a Cholesky decomposition inside `Compile` (the builtin one cannot be compiled). For example, we can steal the [procedural algorithm from this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6673/whats-the-most-functional-way-to-do-cholesky-decomposition).
We slightly modify it to find the transpose of the Cholesky decomposition, so that the matrix multiplication is more natural with our array shape, and we also only allow real matrices.

```
multinormalVariate = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, {S, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}},
  Module[{d, A, iidnorm, x},
    dimens = Length@S;
    A = Table[0.0, {j, d}, {i, d}];
    Do[
      Do[
        If[i == j,
          A[[i, i]] = Sqrt[S[[i, i]] - Sum[A[[k, i]]^2, {k, 1, i - 1}]];,
          A[[j, i]] = (S[[i, j]] - Sum[A[[k, i]]*A[[k, j]], {k, 1, j - 1}])/A[[j, j]];
        ];,
        {i, j, d}];,
      {j, d}
    ];
    (*A is triangular, but Dot is faster than taking advantage of this in a loop*)
    (v + #) & /@ (RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, dimens}].A)
  ],
  CompilationTarget->"C"
];
```

In my tests, this function scales about the same as the builtin function with respect to `n`, where most of the work is in matrix multiplication and choosing samples. However, the builtin one scales better for large `d`. A more efficient decomposer would be needed. For `d` that aren't too large (<~500), this still may be useful in a large compiled function where you want to limit calls to `MainEvaluate`.

```
Module[{d = 10, n = 10000, S, A, v, data1, data2, t},
  A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {d, d}];
  S = A.Transpose[A];
  v = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, d];
  {t, data1} = AbsoluteTiming@multinormalVariate[v, S, n]; Print@t;
  {t, data2} = AbsoluteTiming@RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[v, S], n]; Print@t;
  Print[Norm /@ {v - Mean@data1, v - Mean@data2}];
  Print[Norm /@ {Covariance[data1] - S, Covariance[data2] - S}]
]
```

Edit: this decomposition will fail for singular or poorly conditioned `S`.