# Is there any way to compile and export LearnedDistribution?

Tags: export, distributions, machine-learning, compile

I use the [LearnDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LearnDistribution.html) function to learn the distribution of some data. Then, I want to export some code to sample from that learned distribution. I tried to use [Compile](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) as follows

```
compFun=Compile[{}, RandomVariate[ld]]
```

where `ld` is a LearnedDistribution. However, this fails and the function cannot be compiled and exported. Is there any way to export a function to sample from a LearnedDistribution so that it can be used in another language, like Python?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck: [Which Distributions can be Compiled using RandomVariate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1124/27951) and [List of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/27951).

Comment: Is the resulting `LearnedDistribution` a kernel density distribution?  If so, getting the pieces to obtain random samples in an external program should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: @JimB Yes, the result uses kernel density estimation. How would I go about exporting it? If the LearnedDistribution were a mixture of Gaussians, I thought about exporting the mean and cov. of each Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the links. It seems that the issue is with the preprocessing stage because that is what the error indicates cannot be compiled. It seems like in general the ML functions like Classify and Predict also cannot be compiled, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the option `Method -> "KernelDensityEstimation"` in `LearnDistribution`, then the estimated bandwidth can be extracted.  Call that value `bw`.  (And I'm assuming that a Gaussian kernel will be used.)

```
(* Generate some data *)
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]

(* Use LearnDistribution  *)
ld = LearnDistribution[data, Method -> "KernelDensityEstimation"]
```

Based on the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243541/how-to-extract-items-from-a-learneddistribution-object) from @MarcoB one can obtain the bandwidth of the Gaussian kernel with

```
bw = First[ld]["Model", "KernelSize"]
(* 0.510338 *)
```

Now armed with the bandwidth (i.e., `"KernelSize"`) to obtain a random sample from that estimated distribution one first randomly selects an observation from the original data.  Then select a random sample from a normal distribution with a mean of the random observation and a standard deviation of `bw`.  (Or equivalently, select a random sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation `bw` and then add in a random selection from the original data.)

```
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[data[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[data]}]]], bw]]
```

It might even make more sense to write code in the external application that just uses the data, the estimated bandwidth, and whatever random functions are available especially if multiple random samples are contemplated.

I'll ignore the use of `Compile` (another subject I know little about).

For a much, much better description of this process see @whuber's answer at  [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321542/how-can-i-draw-a-value-randomly-from-a-kernel-density-estimate).