# How to extract items from a LearnedDistribution object?

Tags: filtering, associations

I have never understood how to use `Cases` to extract items from objects (other than exactly copying code written by others which, again, means I don't understand).

I have a `LearnedDistribution` object that upon using `FullForm` I see the item I want:

```
Rule["KernelSize", 0.5103377664280484`]
```

I've been able to obtain the `"KernelSize"` with the following:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
ld = LearnDistribution[data, Method -> "KernelDensityEstimation"]
kernelSize = Cases[ld, First@Association[_]][[1, 6, 2]]
(* 0.510338 *)
```

But using the index `[[1, 6, 2]]` has to be fragile at best.  What is a less fragile and more *Mathematica* way to get that value?

This is related to my partial answer about [exporting information to obtain random samples from a `LearnedDistribution`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242474/is-there-any-way-to-compile-and-export-learneddistribution?noredirect=1#comment611915_242474) object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the output of `LearnDistribution` is a `LearnedDistribution` object, and since its contents is an association, I'd recommend interrogating the association directly via its keys. To extract the kernel size, then, you could use:

```
First[ld]["Model", "KernelSize"]

(* Out: 0.510338 *)
```

In the above, `First[ld]` returns the association that contains all the juicy bits. I then found the rights keys to use on it by inspecting the `InputForm` of the `LearnedDistribution` object (which I find more readable than the `FullForm` at least for a first glance).

---

In passing, I like to use the combination `ld // InputForm // SequenceForm` which I've learned from Carl Woll [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149610/27951): it gives nice "parseable" text where e.g. multiple clicks work to expand selection like in regular code (which doesn't work directly on the normal output of `InputForm`).

Comment: Thank you for both answers:  how to get the kernel size and `InputForm// SequenceForm` approach!

Comment: @JimB You are very welcome. Thank you for the accept as well!

Comment: I found especially the `ld // InputForm` suggestion very useful. I am trying to use this trick to extract the parameters of a multivariate Gaussian mixture fit. Everything I need is there, it's just seriously underdocumented...