# Fast multivariate Cauchy sampling?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I've been using the code below to efficiently sample from multivariate Gaussian with diagonal covariance matrix. Now I want to try the same for Cauchy samples, however replacing `NormalDistribution` with `CauchyDistribution` fails with `CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {{1.54755,-2.73921},{1.28524,-1.49352}} should be a machine-size real number.`

I suspect `CauchyDistribution` is not supported by compile. Is there a workaround?

Compilation speeds up multivariate Gaussian sampling by an order of magnitude. (related [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282210/speeding-up-gaussian-sampling))

```
gaussianSampler[mu_, diag_] := 
  With[{d = Length[diag]}, Assert[d > 0];
      Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
        Module[{vals},
          vals = 
             mu + Sqrt[diag]*# & /@ 
              RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {Max[n, 1], d}]]]];

sampler = gaussianSampler[{0, 0}, {1, 2}];
sampler[5]
```

Comment: Erm. Why don't you just use `RandomVariate[
 MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], DiagonalMatrix[diag]], {n, d}]`? It seems to be at least twice as fast as `sampler`.

Comment: `ConstantArray[mu, n] + 
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}] . DiagonalMatrix[diag]` would have the same effect.

Comment: So, maybe `ConstantArray[mu, n] + 
 RandomVariate[CauchyDistribution[0., 1.], {n, d}].DiagonalMatrix[diag]` does what you want?

Comment: Also Maybe helpful here to bypass problems with `CauchyDistribution` not being compileable:
$$ $$
If $u$ is a uniform r.v. on [0,1], you can get a r.v. $x$ distributed as the standard Cauchy distribution by the transform:
${\displaystyle x=\tan \left(\pi (u-{\frac {1}{2}})\right)}$

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher that solution is slow for large dimensionality. Just forming the diagonal matrix takes longer than sampling

Comment: Ah, then try `DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[diag]]`.

Comment: `MultinormalDistribution` instantiates a dense $d\times d$ matrix, so it only works for small $d$

Comment: A Cauchy distribution is a t distribution with df = 1. The t is a scale mixture of normal. You need a fast gamma generator and a fast normal generator to get this. Just check the Wikipedia page for multivariate t.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches with timings...

Set parameters.

```
n = 100000; (* Sample size *)
d = 1000; (* Dimension *)
mu0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], d];
sigma0 = RandomVariate[ChiSquareDistribution[4], d];
```

Based on @ydd 's comment (assuming all values of `sigma0` are positive):

```
cauchySampler1[mu_, sigma_] := Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{vals},
   vals = mu + sigma*Tan[π (# - 1/2)] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Max[n, 1], Length[sigma]}]]]
sampler1 = cauchySampler1[mu0, sigma0];
AbsoluteTiming[data = sampler1[n];]
(* {1.16369, Null} *)
```

Direct approach:

```
cauchySampler2[mu_, sigma_, n_] := 
  mu + sigma # & /@ RandomVariate[CauchyDistribution[0, 1], {n, Length[sigma]}];
AbsoluteTiming[data = cauchySampler2[mu0, sigma0, n];]
(* {1.99362, Null} *)
```

Improvements in speed might likely need knowledge as to what you want to do with these samples especially making use of the lack of any dependence among samples.