# Compiling a function that uses MapThread

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I'm looking for tips on quickly applying the following update to $B$ pairs of $(w_i,x_i)$

$$\text{step}(w_i,x_i)=w_i-a x_i \langle w_i, x_i \rangle$$

Below is a readable but very slow version `batchStep` which uses `MapThread` which seems unsupported by `FunctionCompile`.

What's a good pattern for compiling a function like this, `For` loops writing into pre-allocated array?

```
d = 2;
h = ConstantArray[1., d];
B = 200;
a = 1.;

step[w_, x_] = w - a x x . w;
dist = MultinormalDistribution[DiagonalMatrix[h]];
batchStep[W_] := 
  With[{X = RandomVariate[dist, B]}, MapThread[step, {W, X}]];

W0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {B, d}];
Nest[batchStep, W0, 100]; // Timing
```

Here's an attempt with `FunctionCompile` which fails with `Cannot find a definition for the function Closure CreateRaw that \ takes an argument with the type PackedArray[Real64, 1:Integer64]`

1. Is `For` loop that writes into pre-allocated array a correct replacement for `MapThread` in this setting?
2. Is there a way to specify all intermediate arguments to be `Real32` (if it matters for performance)

```
d = 2;
h = ConstantArray[1., d];
B = 200;
a = 1.;
fun = Function[{Typed[W, "Real32"]},
   Module[{data, out, i, X, diagSqrt},
    diagSqrt = Sqrt[h];
    X = diagSqrt*# & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {B, d}];
    out = ConstantArray[0., {B, d}];
    For[i = 1, i <= B, i += 1,
     out[[i]] = step[W[[i]], X[[i]]]];
    out
    ]
   ];
dec = FunctionDeclaration[fun, Typed[{"Real32"} -> "Real32"]@fun];
cf = FunctionCompile[dec, fun]
```

Comment: Haven't looked into it, but I'd guess the real barrier is not `MapThread`, but `RandomVariate`, see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1124/1871

Comment: RandomVariate is about half of the time when using MKL initialization

Comment: I believe, currently, `MapThread` is only defined for `"DenseArray"`. Check for detail in system files here: `SystemFiles\Components\Compile\TypeSystem\Declarations\RectangularArray\DenseArray\Functional\MapThread.m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `MapThread` is so optimized that there's no point in using compilation in this case. Every modification I tried makes code slower.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 1000;
B = 1000;
a = 2/(d + 1);
numSteps = 100;
sample := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {B, d}];
W0 = sample;

Print["matrix"];
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MKL"];
batchStep[W_] := With[{s = sample}, W - a*s (Total[W*s, {2}])];
Nest[batchStep, W0, numSteps] // First // First // AbsoluteTiming


Print["mapthread"];
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MKL"];
step[w_, x_] = w - a x x . w;
batchStep[W_] := MapThread[step, {W, sample}];
Nest[batchStep, W0, numSteps] // First // First // AbsoluteTiming


Print["compiled mapthread"];
d = 1000;
B = 1000;
a = 2/(d + 1);
numSteps = 100;
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MKL"];
s = sample;
batchStep = Compile[{{W, _Real, 2}},
   With[{a0 = a},
    MapThread[#1 - a0 *#2*#2 . #1 &, {W, 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {B, d}]}]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
Nest[batchStep, W0, numSteps] // First // First // AbsoluteTiming
```